# What Android tools and methods work best to find memory/resource leaks?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I've got an Android app developed, and I'm at the point of a phone app development where everything seems to be working well and you want to declare victory and ship, but you know there just have to be some memory and resource leaks in there; and there's only 16mb of heap on the Android and its apparently surprisingly easy to leak in an Android app.

I've been looking around and so far have only been able to dig up info on 'hprof' and 'traceview' and neither gets a lot of favorable reviews.

What tools or methods have you come across or developed and care to share maybe in an OS project?

Comment: Can I vote to have Р̀СТȢѸ́ФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ change his name to something human readable.

Comment: would it be ok to reopen this question if we remove the word "Android Tools" from the question-title? The answers found here were quite usefull to solve my memory leak problems

Comment: Okay, so I have a user constantly switching between activities, meaning they may have switched 15 activities in 20 seconds. Could that be a cause of an out of memory error? What should I do to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Can't provide this as a response because the question has been closed, however I'd recommend taking a look at [Leak Canary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary). Just use your app, open and close activities and let the library do it's job. It will even tell you about where the leak occured. Just give the leak analyzer some time to do its work after the leak occured - it usually takes around 2 minutes or more until the source of the leak has been found. After that it will present it to you neatly in-app. No extra tools needed!

Answer (score 29):

Get the Eclipse Memory Analyzer ( http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)
Check http://kohlerm.blogspot.com/2010/02/android-memory-usage-analysis-slides.html
and http://kohlerm.blogspot.com/search/label/memory

Answer (score 28):

Mostly for Google travelers from the future:

Most java tools are unfortunately unsuitable for this task, because they only analyze the JVM-Heap. Every Android Application also has a native heap, though, which also has to fit within the ~16 MB limit. It's usually used for bitmap data, for example. So you can run quite easily into Out Of Memory errors even though your JVM-Heap is chillin around 3 MBs, if you use a lot of drawables.

Comment: starting Android 3.0 (honeycomb) drawables are stored in the heap

Comment: @Timo then what would you use to detect leaks in the native heap?

Comment: Testing, lots of testing. Problem is that you can't even really tell how much memory your app is using, due to memory sharing and other optimization techniques. You can get memory readings using the usual shell commands, but those are very, very rough estimates.

Answer (score 20):

The answer from @hp.android works well if you are just working with bitmap backgrounds but, in my case, I had a `BaseAdapter` providing a set of `ImageView`s for a `GridView`. I modified the `unbindDrawables()` method as advised so that the condition is:

```
if (view instanceof ViewGroup && !(view instanceof AdapterView)) {
  ...
}
```

but the problem then is that the recursive method never processes the children of the `AdapterView`. To address this, I instead did the following:

```
if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
  ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
  for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++)
    unbindDrawables(viewGroup.getChildAt(i));

  if (!(view instanceof AdapterView))
    viewGroup.removeAllViews();
}
```

so that the children of the `AdapterView` are still processed -- the method just doesn't attempt to remove all children (which is unsupported).

This doesn't quite fix the problem however since `ImageView`s manage a bitmap that is not their background. I therefore added the following. It's not ideal but it works:

```
if (view instanceof ImageView) {
  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
  imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
}
```

Overall the `unbindDrawables()` method is then:

```
private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
  if (view.getBackground() != null)
    view.getBackground().setCallback(null);

  if (view instanceof ImageView) {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
    imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
  } else if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
    for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++)
    unbindDrawables(viewGroup.getChildAt(i));

    if (!(view instanceof AdapterView))
      viewGroup.removeAllViews();
  }
}
```

I'm hoping there is a more principled approach to freeing up such resources.

Answer (score 12):

Good Google I/O talk (2011) on Memory Management in Android, as well as details on tools + techniques for memory profiling:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

Comment: Or the corresponding blog post: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html

Comment: Okay, so I have a user constantly switching between activities, meaning they may have switched 15 activities in 20 seconds. Could that be a cause of an out of memory error? What should I do to fix it? Thanks!'

Answer (score 4):

Valgrind has been ported to Android (sponsored by Mozilla). See [Valgrind on Android — Current Status](http://blog.mozilla.com/jseward/2011/09/27/valgrind-on-android-current-status/) and [Support Running Valgrind for Android on ARM](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=266035) (comment 67).

Comment: that would require a custom rom to be built.

Answer (score 1):

Well, those are the tools that hook with the unique formats that Android uses..I think what you may be unsatisfied with is the underlying testing code framework in use..

Have you tried mock testing areas of code using the Android Mock Framework?

Comment: not so much, testing of that nature isn't so much the issue as recording what's actually happening while the application runs, what I really need is a resource/memory leak profiling tool