# Extending ImageView causes memory leak

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, imageview

Good day

I'm extending the `ImageView` class because I need it to be a square, the problem is that it seems to be causing a memory leak, because if I use the not extended `ImageView` class there is no output in MAT. This is the extended version, as you can see is very simple:

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {

    public SquareImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    }

}
```

and I'm implementing it as a `GridView` item, something like this:

```
<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:foreground="@drawable/item_button">

    <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate
            android:id="@+id/progressBarCircularIndeterminate"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/orange"/>

    <!-- if I use <ImageView/>, everything is ok -->
    <com.example.widgets.SquareImageView
            android:id="@+id/picture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

This is what I get in the histogram after opening and closing the fragment containing the gridview 10 times, as you can see the retained heap is huge, at this point I already forced the GC:

[image]

The list with incoming references of 1 of the 10 retained objects:

[image]

And the path to gc roots (excluding weak references):

[image]

I managed to reduce the retained heap by recycling the ImageView bitmaps:

[image]

But I can't figure out why those 10 objects are being retained. As I said in the beginning, if I use `ImageView` instead of the extended one, there is no leak at all. If you could give me a hint, it would be great.

Comment: What's holding onto your CardView as shown in the path to gc roots (excluding weak references) view?

Comment: Any solution for this issue?