# tool to check memory leaks in android

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks

Is there any nice tool to check memory leaks in android?

any help will be appreciative.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tool "Traceview" will also be helpful to you. This comes with the android sdk.
Refer to the following link for more detail.

[<strike>http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html</strike>](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html)

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/traceview.html

Comment: @RanjithKumar Corrected

Comment: Thanks for response

Answer (score 5):

You can try using Memory Analyzer to check Memory leaks in Android

http://kohlerm.blogspot.com/2009/04/analyzing-memory-usage-off-your-android.html

Answer (score 1):

A different and more detailed version of this question is discussed in that address imho [What Android tools and methods work best to find memory/resource leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147172/what-android-tools-and-methods-work-best-to-find-memory-resource-leaks)

Answer (score 0):

http://source.android.com/source/download.html mentions about tool called Valgrind:

You might also want Valgrind, a tool that will help you find memory leaks, stack corruption, array bounds overflows, etc.

```
 $ sudo apt-get install valgrind
```

Comment: I think this answer is outdated. Besides that, I think it only applies to the NDK, not pure Java/Dalvik VM memory "leaks".