# Android MediaPlayer TextureView play video oom

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-mediaplayer, android-textureview

I use `MediaPlayer` & `TextureView`，Repeats the video. But within a short while the program crashed, cause by OOM. I called `mediaPlayer.release()` in `onSurfaceTextureDestroyed()`, but it still crashes.

Does any body has the same problem ?

This is my code :

```
    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
        surface=null;
        stop();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.release();

        }catch (Exception e){
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void stop(){

        try {
            if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                return;
            }
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }catch (Exception e){
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like a memory leak. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8174140/5241933)

Comment: Yes,it is a memory leak.But I don't know why，play video repeat about 20 times,it will crash

Comment: There are quite a few similar questions around - please search first and see if one of them fits