# My Android app is using too much RAM(0.8 GB) in the Native section. How to reduce it?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

My app doesn't contain any native code but I am using the following libraries :

`Fireabse auth`,`database`,`storage`,`messaging`

`Google Maps`, `Location`

`SendGrid` - for sending emails

`RazorPay`

`Glide`

When my app starts, the RAM taken by Native section is around **180 MB** and after I open a fragment which reads data from the real-time database a couple of times, the RAM usage by Native section shoots up to **800 MB**!

How can I reduce this?

**Edit:**

My dependencies

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.4.5'
    implementation files('libs/sendgrid-0.1.2-jar.jar')
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.mklimek:frame-video-view:1.3.3'
```

Here's how I query data from the database

```
DatabaseReference carReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        carReference.child("carDetails").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ArrayList<String> carsOwnedByUser = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot carDetails : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    CarDetails car = carDetails.getValue(CarDetails.class);

                    if (userId.equals(car.getUserId())) {
                        carsOwnedByUser.add(car.getMake());
                    }
                }

                String selectedCar = sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_SELECTED_CAR, "None");

                if (carsOwnedByUser.size() > 0) {
                    if (selectedCar.equals("None")) {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        editor.putString(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_SELECTED_CAR, carsOwnedByUser.get(0));
                        editor.apply();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

**What I have tried:**

I have tried disabling the disk Caching in Glide and I have tried setting the DatabaseReferenec.getInstance().setPersistacneEnabled() and keepSynced() to false but they didn't help.

**Edit 2:**

I checked the heap dump in the profiler and saw that Bitmap was taking 300 MB in the native section

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOc5u.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure you want us to solve your query without getting single line of your code?

Comment: What piece of code can help in solving this problem? I am completely clueless about this. I guess I will add my dependencies and the way I am querying my realtime database.

Comment: how much/which data are you reading from the DB? Are you sure that 800 mb ram is a problem? Check on lower-ram device (emulator) to see if it will cause problems.

Comment: Yup, on lower end devices(3 GB RAM or less) the app crashes with a FatalException. Could not allocate x bytes.

Comment: This is probaly due to a `memory leak` where your app allocates memory that is never deallocated. Have you searched the internet for the term "android memory leak" (i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174140/android-memory-leak ) ?

Comment: So please provide more information about your use of images: when and how do you load them, how many are on the screen at the same time, how big are they (width and height, original file size), do you process them (apply filters, crop etc.).

Comment: I use Glide to load them. Glide.with(context).load(getResources(...)).into(). I do no processing on the images and the images are 1-2 MB large. Nd Glide should take care about the size of image automatically.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, below line is main reason for high memory usage.

```
carReference.child("carDetails"). addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...)
```

Above line load all carDetails's children from firebase database to device's memory. So avoid using that. If you still need to use that then paginate data using proper combination of `startAt()`, `endAt()`, `limitToFirst()` and `limitToLast()` query filters. [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data)

If you still unable to make correct pagination then go ahead and use proper database structure, so you can fetch required details using simple query. [Best Practices for data structure](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure)

Comment: This didn't help and in the profiler(heap dump) it shows Bitmap is taking around 300 MB in the Native section.

https://imgur.com/lfiNueY