# Quickly unload bitmaps from memory

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am creating this Android game in Java. I have quite a lot of images but don't need to use them all at once so I have created a Resource Manger class which takes care of the Bitmaps that are in use. However, I have found it quite slow to clear the Bitmap out of the memory. I am currently doing something like this:

```
bitmap.recycle()
bitmap = null

System.gc (also tried Runtime.getRuntime().gc())
```

Firstly, is there any way to quicker unload the bitmaps from the memory or is it possible to somehow check if they actually ARE cleared so I can make the loading screen depend on that as well?

Comment: You might consider using an existing bitmap caching engine rather than rolling your own: http://www.senab.co.uk/2012/12/18/android-bitmapcache-the-rebirth/

Comment: The reason is it slow is you are calling the gc.  Let it run when needed.  +1 @CommonsWare no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: calling .recycle() and setting it to null should actually just do it. No need to call .gc() :)

Comment: What I ment with slow is: I am tracking the memory usage and it takes like 10 sec for it to get taken out of the memory. Would it be possible that it's actually deleted if we're about to OOM?

Comment: @RasmusAppelkvist - the JVM will aggressively run garbage collection if it is about to run out of memory. Your responsibility ends with  making sure that objects *can* be garbage collected.

Comment: To that, I will add that each call to System.GC will make a full garbage collection; which will be a slow operation even if there is nothing to collect.  It's usually a better idea to leave it to the Android system; which will probably choose the frequency and - most important - the type of GC to do in a much better way than simply calling a full GC each time you release a bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that the garbage collector will actually be run when we attempt for [System.gc()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#gc%28%29) as gc() expects certain preconditions like resource hunger. So it is quite obvious that calling gc() is just wasting critical CPU Cycles. As a developer we can make unnecessary objects for gc collectable by nullifying the references.

There are couple of optimization techniques that can be helpful while creating a gaming system(game).

1. Use Texture. Here is an [example](http://tkcodesharing.blogspot.in/2008/05/working-with-textures-in-androids.html).
2. Use Sprite and SpriteSheets( It gives less overhead to the system than loading individual bitmaps). many open source game engines are there who uses this.If you don't want to use them get an idea how to create from scratch from these sources.
3. Use these standard android doc for how to [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)
   and [Caching Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) for better usage of bitmap. The idea is when users device is not efficient enough to handle the amount of processing and/or the memory is less for your game you can always scale down the bitmap(compromise with quality for better response).
4. Always test your app against memory leak problems. Here is a [nice post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646157/tool-to-check-memory-leaks-in-android) that will help.
5. Keep InMemory(don't release once used) items that are used several times inside the game in the same scene. The reason is it takes lot of time to load images into the memory.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As SylvainL said, System.gc and friends collects the full garbage and can be quite slow. The Java machine runs the GC periodically, and period is finetuned depending on how much free memory is  available at a given moment.

Best choice for me is to use some kind of bitmap pooling: having a set of prefab Bitmap instances that you can acquire from and release to the pool, and managing Buffer instances in a cache applying LRU policies.

With proper finetuning, you can get zero cost on creating and destroying Bitmap instances as they're pooled, and Buffer instances containing bitmap data will be dynamically loaded to and unloaded from memory depending on usage.