# How to manage memory/cache from code?

Tags: android, caching, memory-management

My app is crashing after longer use - runs out of memory.
I am closing all activities after switching to next one, but I still have that problem.
Is it possible to programmatically clear cache / memory, so application does not run out resources?
Can I use getCacheDir() to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently your app is leaking memory. Make sure you clean up unused resources, close databases, reuse variables, etc.

Also refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147172/what-android-tools-and-methods-work-best-to-find-memory-resource-leaks) on how to track down memory leaks and how to avoid them.