# Detect memory leak in android native code

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks, android-ndk

What is the best way to detect memory leaks in native code built with the android NDK?

Is there any tool like valgrind that I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You load *.so library with `System.loadLibrary`, than call any jni functions. So you can define "startup" and "cleanup" functions - you can do your initialzation in former func and release all resources in latter. In this case it's possible to use any from large amount of available leak tracers - for example you can see following:

http://dmalloc.com/

http://www.andreasen.org/LeakTracer/

http://memwatch.sourceforge.net/

http://mpatrol.sourceforge.net/

About valgrind: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7815977/814297