# How to detect memory leak

Tags: android, eclipse, memory-management

I faced some issues related to MemoryOutOfBounds exception in android. I found There are two reasons behind this

(1) Thread created are alive and not destroyed anywhere

(2) Memory leak.

We can detect thread information in eclipse. But how to know at which line of my code memory leak occurs when I execute my application. MAT works differently. MAT is static.
Is there any plug-ins or any way to know memory-leak in eclipse?

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might be useful.

[What Android tools and methods work best to find memory/resource leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147172/what-android-tools-and-methods-work-best-to-find-memory-resource-leaks)

Answer (score 7):

You don't need a memory leak to get an OutOfMemoryError, simply using too much memory in your app will cause it.

Answer (score 5):

You can have a look at the following links regarding how to avoid memory-leaks:

- http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-leaks/
- http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/How-to-avoid-Memory-leak-issue-in-Java-1001.php