# Is it possible to know at runtime when Garbage collection is occuring?

Tags: android, garbage-collection

Basically, I am using achartengine for a charting application. It seems like i have a memory leak somewhere so garbage collection is occuring somewhat often. The problem is, whenever GC occurs, it messes up my chart. I can call repaint() to fix it, but I would need to know when GC.

Image of the messed up chart below

[URL=http://img166.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=403999439_device_2011_07_11_122608_122_441lo.png][IMG]http://img166.imagevenue.com/loc441/th_403999439_device_2011_07_11_122608_122_441lo.png[/IMG][/URL]

Comment: Redrawing your chart is stop-gap measure. I would strongly urge you to try to find and fix the memory leak instead. You can find some helpful hints [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147172/what-android-tools-and-methods-work-best-to-find-memory-resource-leaks)

Comment: Thank you. I am doing that. But also wanted to know for personal knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Each Java Object have a method finalize() which is called just before the GC try to "delete" the object. [example](http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/enterprise-java-beans/how-to-write-finalization-code-in.html)

Hope this help.