# Memory allocation in Android widget

Tags: android, memory, widget

I have developed a widget in Android and it uses too much RAM (over 30 MB). What can it be that takes up so much memory? The widget is a clock and weather widget that uses different skins (saved as drawables).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say could be a lot of thing. But lucky for you Android DDMS has a Allocation Tracker, that might help you solve your problem.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also using plugin [Memory Analyzer tool](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/)

Detail you can refer:

1. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147172/what-android-tools-and-methods-work-best-to-find-memory-resource-leaks](http://1.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147172/what-android-tools-and-methods-work-best-to-find-memory-resource-leaks)
2. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-do-i-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android)

Another good document guide how to well design layout for widget:

[http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html)