# Stress testing an android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an android app that appears to be working fine - but I wish to ensure that I have not just been getting away with problems like memory leaks, thread lockups etc. Is there some utility, or mode within eclipse, that will highlight potential problems that may occur in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- [StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) is a way of guarding against accidental disk or network access on the main thread.
- [Android Lint](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint) is a recent addition to the SDK tools, to catch potential bugs and usability issues.
- [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) is another non-Android-specific static analysis tool.
- Android 4.0 (ICS) devices have several development options (in the Settings menu) you can enable to catch potential problems:

  - **Don't keep activities** forces activities to be destroyed on exit
  - **Show screen updates** so you can tell if you're doing too much rendering
  - ...and more
- [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) can tell you what your threads are doing.
- See [What Android tools and methods work best to find memory/resource leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147172/what-android-tools-and-methods-work-best-to-find-memory-resource-leaks) for information about tracking memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried static code analyzers? For example [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net) is an excellent tool for discovering possible problems in your code.

Depending on your application you might also release [Monkey](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkey.html) on your UI with a large amount of events and analyze the memory afterwards to discover possible leaks and crashes.