# Possible to cancel notifyDataSetChanged (adapter refresh)?

Tags: android, android-adapter, baseadapter

Once I have issued `notifyDataSetChanged` on my custom `BaseAdapter`, is there a way to cancel the refresh of the adapter?

For example, I return to some screen and `notifyDataSetChanged` has been called to refresh the `ListView` or `GridView`. A user then opens another screen before the refresh has been finished and the adapter refresh is cancelled since no longer needed.

I hope I explained this well. If something isn't clear, please let me know so that I can explain it a bit more.

Comment: how big of a problem is this?

Comment: @gunar At some point when I navigate to another screen the app crashes due to lack of memory. It seems that the adapter is still consuming memory (or I thought to) while another screen starts using it as well.

Comment: Memory leaks are a different story. Maybe you should first detect them. Maybe start with this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147172/what-android-tools-and-methods-work-best-to-find-memory-resource-leaks