# Binary XML file <line 20>: Error inflating class <Unknown>

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

> 06-07 15:02:07.048: E/dalvikvm-heap(1657): 9007416-byte external allocation too large for this process.
> 06-07 15:02:07.098: E/GraphicsJNI(1657): VM won't let us allocate 9007416 bytes

[image: Screenshot]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="top|left|right"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/top_red_bar"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   
    android:src="@drawable/job_bar" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="238dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="123dp"
    android:src="@drawable/button" 
    android:alpha="0.85"
    android:onClick="myhandler"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:src="@drawable/button" 
    android:alpha="0.85"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
    android:src="@drawable/employer" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
    android:src="@drawable/jobseekers" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView6"
    android:text="Employer"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
    android:text="Job Seekers"
    
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

My app gets crashed with error statement `Binary XML file <line 20>: Error inflating class <Unknown>`.
Why does this happen?? Could anyone fix this? And interestingly, when I remove all code except background, it works!!!

Comment: post the who error not just part of it

Comment: post error logcat of 10 to 20 lines, that normally is the red portion of lines in logcat

Comment: @Hamad These two lines of error displayed in log cat:               06-07 15:02:07.048: E/dalvikvm-heap(1657): 9007416-byte external allocation too large for this process.
06-07 15:02:07.098: E/GraphicsJNI(1657): VM won't let us allocate 9007416 bytes

Comment: @user2750644 Are you testing on emulator?

Comment: yes i'm testing on emulator

Comment: What is line 20 in xml file? Is the drawable 9MB?

Comment: Guys, Now i installed it on my device, its working good. Problem was that, emulator does not supporting large memory. Fixed!!! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @user2750644 As I suggest in answer.

Comment: Please, keeep in mind that older devices may have a limited memory. Consider using a smaller image for your background. After all, being stretched, it will give the same **blur effect**.

Comment: @user2750644 : **"Problem was that, emulator does not supporting large memory. Fixed!!!"** : Don't be so sure of that. As Der Golem points out, different devices and Android versions will have limited amounts of memory to handle things like images. Just because it works on your device doesn't mean it will work on *all* devices.

Comment: Squonk is right. You should try to make your app work on the largest possible amount of devices. And the emulator is really handy to show you **design or code  flaws**.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `@drawable` parts i.e the size of images you using for this layout - the VM runs out of memory when decoding the bitmap. Make the image dimensions smaller.

**Edit**

As I see from your logcat 
You are leaking resources (most likely the **Drawable** object). For more info see at [tools in What Android tools and methods work best to find memory/resource leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147172/what-android-tools-and-methods-work-best-to-find-memory-resource-leaks)

Comment: I tried to remove background and run, but still same error popping.

Comment: @user2750644 please post logcat exception